# Missing Rect Objects in D3 Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, bar-chart, data-visualization

I have been working on creating a simple D3 bar chart visualization but for some reason, the bars (rects) aren't appearing in my viz. The visualization uses a .csv as the raw data used for the visualization. The only part of the chart I can get to work is the axes, but even when I change the order of the function calls when drawing the axes, they disappear as well.

I've attempted to use the `.selectAll("rect")` function call as well as `.join("rect")` and `.append("rect")` function calls but nothing seems to work. The code I've written is below. I've tried many online resources to determine the reasoning for why the rect objects won't show up to no avail.

I'm using d3.js API version 5.

```
<script>
    var margin = { top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 30 },
        width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
        .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

    //defines the x-axis which is based on a numerical format
    var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .rangeRound([0, width]);

    //defines the y-axis which is based on a numerical format    
    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .rangeRound([height, 0]);


    d3.csv("http://raw.githubusercontent.com/naija-queen/Raw-Data/master/crashing.csv").then(function (data) {
        //sets the domain of the x-axis
        xScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
            return (Number(d.episode));
        })])

        //sets the domain of the y-axis
        yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
            return (Number(d.percent));
        })])

        //draws the x-axis
        svg.append('g')
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        //.ticks() command allows you to define how many ticks you want to see in the visualization
        .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(16))

        //draws the y-axis
        svg.append("g")
        //for some reason moving arround the function call below makes the y-axis disappear
        .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale))
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Percent Watched");

        //parts of a bar chart
        svg.append('bar')
        .attr("fill", "lightskyblue")
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
        .join("rect")
        // d => is basically function(d){}
        .attr("x", d => xScale(Number(d.episode)))
        .attr("y", d => yScale(Number(d.percent)))
        .attr("width", 20)
        .attr("height", d => yScale(0) - yScale(Number(d.percent)));          
    });

</script>
```

**I am a complete novice at D3, so please provide an explanation for your answer if you can.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems lie here:

```
svg.append('bar')
    .attr("fill", "lightskyblue")
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .join("rect")
```

You're appending a `bar` element to the SVG - this isn't a valid SVG element, and it won't render, nor will its children (the rectangles you want to draw).

I'm just going to use the `enter` selection (the join combines functionality of enter/exit/update, but we should use understand the enter functionality first):

```
   svg
    .selectAll(null) 
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")    
    .attr("...")
```

An enter selection creates an element in the DOM for each item in the data array that doesn't have a corresponding element in the DOM already. I can select all the `rect` elements with `selectAll("rect")`, but for each one that I select that already exists, one item in the data array won't be entered. So I'm selecting nothing: `.selectAll(null)`, which creates an empty selection containing no DOM elements. This way every item that is in the data array is entered, regardless of what is in the DOM already.

*In your case, using `selectAll("rect")` is fine, as no `rect`s will be selected with `svg.selectAll("rect")`*

Now I bind the data array: `.data(data)`

And then I access the enter selection: `.enter()`. This returns a selection of placeholders. As we selected nothing, one placeholder is created for each item in the data array. Now I can then add SVG elements with `.append("rect")`. With this, I have a selection of newly created rectangles. Now I can modify them as desired, for example, by using the bound datum to set their width/height, x/y, etc.

*For simplicity, I've only presented using the enter selection here. If I use `selectAll("rect")` and rects exist already, now I have potentially update and/or exit selections - which would allow updating the existing rectangles for which there are corresponding items in the data array or exiting of elements for which there are no longer corresponding items in the data array.*

```js
var margin = { top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 30 },
        width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
        .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

    //defines the x-axis which is based on a numerical format
    var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .rangeRound([0, width]);

    //defines the y-axis which is based on a numerical format    
    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .rangeRound([height, 0]);


    d3.csv("http://raw.githubusercontent.com/naija-queen/Raw-Data/master/crashing.csv").then(function (data) {
        //sets the domain of the x-axis
        xScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
            return (Number(d.episode));
        })])

        //sets the domain of the y-axis
        yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
            return (Number(d.percent));
        })])

        //draws the x-axis
        svg.append('g')
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        //.ticks() command allows you to define how many ticks you want to see in the visualization
        .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(16))

        //draws the y-axis
        svg.append("g")
        //for some reason moving arround the function call below makes the y-axis disappear
        .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale))
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Percent Watched");

        //parts of a bar chart
        svg
        .selectAll(null)
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("fill", "lightskyblue")
        // d => is basically function(d){}
        .attr("x", d => xScale(Number(d.episode)))
        .attr("y", d => yScale(Number(d.percent)))
        .attr("width", 20)
        .attr("height", d => yScale(0) - yScale(Number(d.percent)));          
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Also, if you want your entered elements to be contained in a parent `g`, you can use `selectAll` a nested `g`, such as with:

```
svg
 .append("g")
 .selectAll(null) 
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("rect")    
 .attr("...")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The rectangles finally showed up. Thank you for the explaination as well!